# Array extension of particular type returns an error

Tags: arrays, swift2

I'm trying to create array extension for a specific type of Element.
Here's what I wrote:

(UnElement is a class conforming to the CustomStringConvertible, Equatable, Comparable protocols)

```
extension Array where Element : UnElement {
    mutating func ajoute(new: UnElement) -> Bool {
        if new.pKey == nil {
            return false
        } else {
            if self.contains(new) {
                return false
            } else {
                self.append(new)
                return true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I get an error for the `contains` method:

> Cannot invoke 'contains' with an argument list of type `(UnElement)`

and of course the same with the `append` one.

It looks like as if the type of the elements of the array is not specified, and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast `new` to array's `Element` type:

```
extension Array where Element : UnElement {
    mutating func ajoute(new: UnElement) -> Bool {
        if new.pKey == nil {
            return false
        } else {
            if self.contains(new as! Element) {
                return false
            } else {
                self.append(new as! Element)
                return true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: waoooo .... It works .... But I can't understand why  I have to force casting ... Anyway thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to cast nothing ...

```
class UnElement: Equatable {
    var pKey: Int?
    init(key: Int?) {
        pKey = key
    }
}
func ==(lhs: UnElement, rhs: UnElement)->Bool {
    return lhs.pKey == rhs.pKey
}

extension Array where Element : UnElement {
    mutating func ajoute(new: Element) -> Bool {
        if new.pKey == nil {
            return false
        } else {
            if self.contains(new) {
                return false
            } else {
                self.append(new)
                return true
            }
        }
    }
}

var arr = [UnElement(key: 1), UnElement(key: 2), UnElement(key: nil)]
arr.ajoute(UnElement(key: 1)) // false
arr.ajoute(UnElement(key: 3)) // true
dump(arr)
/*
▿ 4 elements
▿ [0]: UnElement #0
▿ pKey: 1
- Some: 1
▿ [1]: UnElement #1
▿ pKey: 2
- Some: 2
▿ [2]: UnElement #2
- pKey: nil
▿ [3]: UnElement #3
▿ pKey: 3
- Some: 3
*/
```